# Fock Space: I don't understand the definition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, tensor-calculus

My question is really close to this one [Meaning of Fock Space](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/296391/meaning-of-fock-space)

In fact I don't understand why we define Fock space as :

$$\Gamma(H):=\mathbb C\oplus H\oplus H^2\oplus\cdots\oplus H^N\oplus\cdots$$

Indeed, I would define the Fock space as a Hilbert space which is an infinite tensorial product of Hilbert space.

Because for me to write :

$$ |01\rangle = |0\rangle|1\rangle $$ is ***physically*** the same state as  $$ |1\rangle$$

Indeed (for me but I may be wrong), to say "first state is vacuum and second one is with one particle" is physically the same as saying "we have one particle"

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Because the infinite tensorial product simply does not exist. $||\otimes_{n=1}^{+\infty} a_n\psi_n || = |a_n|^{\infty} = \infty$ if $||\psi_n||=1$ and $a_n = a>1$ even if $||\otimes_{n=1}^{+\infty} \psi_n || = 1$. You should exlude certain vectors from the space against the natural structure of tensor product and tensor space.

Comment: Roughly dealing, you may handle the Fock space as if it were an infinite tensor product, but you cannot if you want to be mathematically precise.

Comment: So, is it only for pure mathematical reasons ? If we would'nt have this problem of convergence, then we would use the "more simple" definition of infinite tensor product ?

Comment: That is a question with a very strange status, I cannot answer. physical tools in physics must be logically consistent, first of all (and physically sound obviously). An infinite tensor product is not logically consistent, at least within a natural approach.  This is enough in my view to rule out it. Also because a Fock space is not an absurdly complicated concept...This is different form other tools think of  the Dirac's delta, where the mathematical formalization is a bit more complicated...

Comment: To my experience when physics is correct mathematics can be fixed accordingly. Fock space is just the mathematical notion arising from the physical idea of a quantum system made of an **undefined** number of elementary subsystems...

Comment: Of course things has to be defined mathematically but we still can talk of feeling behind object. The Dirac function when invented had a good physical feeling but not a mathematical one at first. My question is the same : I want to understand if the feeling of an infinite tensorial product is the good to have even if we can't define it mathematically because things would'nt converge (and then we adopt the definition given above)

Answer (score 1):

One has to take into account all the subspaces of definite particle number of the full Hilbert space in order to describe interacting theory, because in QFT particles can be created from the vacuum by operators in the interaction term $H_{int}$ in the Hamiltonian, and annihilated. How are you going to define the action of the creating operator $a_1^{\dagger}$ on your two-particle Hilbert space, if you "absorbed" the state space of the first particle into the second one? The operators (observables) in QFT are defined to act on the full Hilbert space.

Comment: "if you "absorbed" the state space of the first particle into the second one?" I don't understand what you mean ? I just work in a larger space that contains all number of particle ever possible. For me it is the same as studying an object that can move through a line $y=2$ but then decide to go on all the plane. I can describe its movement from the beginning by a movement in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I'm not forced to work in $\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{R}^2$ to study it.